# Find object by id in an array using angular 2 and typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Hello guys i am using asp.net mvc 5.
When i try to find object by id it returns undefined.Here objects are displayed fine when i do console.log(this.vtypes)

**controller.cs:**

```
public JsonResult GetVerificationType(){
        List<verificationType> vlist = new List<verificationType>();
        vlist.Add(new verificationType() { vType = "vtype1", vtypeID = 1 });
        vlist.Add(new verificationType() { vType = "vtype2", vtypeID = 2 });
        vlist.Add(new verificationType() { vType = "vtype3", vtypeID = 3 });
        return Json(vlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
```

**typescript file:**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
model: any = {};
vtypes = [];
constructor(private LoginServiceModule: LoginService, private router: Router, ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.LoginServiceModule.getVerificationTypes().subscribe(x => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) {
            this.vtypes.push(x[i]); <--- x[i].vtypeID doesn't work here
        }
    });
    console.log(this.vtypes); <----- works fine shows array of 3 length
    var item = this.vtypes.find(x => x.vtypeID === 1);
    console.log(item); <---- returns undefined even when vtypeID = 1 is present
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: No. Here i am asking for search result from array. It returns undefined even though objects are displayed in console

Comment: Can you share the `getVerificationTypes` method code and the result of `console.log(this.vtypes)`?

Comment: 0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
   
in object 0

vType
:
"vtype1"
vtypeID
:
1

Comment: I am returning this from controlller
List<verificationType> vlist = new List<verificationType>();
            vlist.Add(new verificationType() { vType = "vtype1", vtypeID = 1 });
            vlist.Add(new verificationType() { vType = "vtype2", vtypeID = 2 });
            vlist.Add(new verificationType() { vType = "vtype3", vtypeID = 3 });

Comment: Can you edit your question and add these info to your question? It's really hard to read it from here..

Comment: @echonax thank you for showing interest in question. I have updated now.

Comment: No problem, I can't see the console.log tho, is it updated?

Comment: yes it is updated.
Sorry i cant copy the code of console.log. But I can tell you all three records are displayed.
Only problem is when i try to find the record using vtypeID it returns undefined

Comment: ok can you try this then: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.vtypes));`

Comment: It shows empty array in console using JSON.stringify

Comment: Ok then it is a duplicate of the link I've given. Let me explain why it gives you the object when you don't use the `JSON.stringify`. It is because objects are mutable. Your console displays your objects' latest value. At first it is empty. When you actually run the console.log it is still empty but after the data arrives your object changes hence it is reflected to the console. Just read the link I've given and tell me the parts you don't understand.

Comment: I am sorry i am pretty new to angular 2 and typescript.
So can you tell me how to tackle this situation

Comment: There's no need to apologize, we all started from 0. Have you read the link? Is it difficult to understand?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43055707/5706293 the **Solution** part. You should do it inside the subscribe.

Comment: Thankyou. No i mean i am already pushing in array inside subscribe.

But how to execute the query outside subscribe

Comment: You should really read the link :-) but as a very quick sum, you can't

Comment: Thank you very much it solved my problem. Actually i am trying my hands on Angular 2. So don't have much knowledge about it.

You were right i was very quick to understand that answer.

Comment: No problem, I'll provide it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the async logic inside the subscribe

```
 this.LoginServiceModule.getVerificationTypes().subscribe(x => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) {
            this.vtypes.push(x[i]); <--- x[i].vtypeID doesn't work here
        }
        console.log(this.vtypes); <----- works fine shows array of 3 length
        var item = this.vtypes.find(x => x.vtypeID === 1);
        console.log(item);
    });
```

Suggested reading: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43055706/5706293)